# How does the performance of String.substring() compare with manual lookups into a copied char[] array?

Tags: string, performance, java-7

I'm looking at a function which continuously scans large volumes of relatively short strings, and generates a large number of substrings from them. The function will be used in a high volume string processing system. I prefer to optimize memory first, CPU second, since I'm experiencing more memory than CPU pressure on the system. In that context, how does performance compare between:

```
//Java-ish PseudoCode
functionParent(List<String> strings) {
  StringBuilder result;
  for(String s : strings) {
    result.appendAll(functionA(s));
  }
}


functionA(String arg1) {
  results.add(arg1.substring(i, i + length)); //hotspot here
}
```

---

and:

```
//Java-ish PseudoCode
functionParent(List<String> strings) {
  StringBuilder result;
  for(String s : strings) {
    result.appendAll(functionB(s.toCharArray()));
  }
}

functionB(char[] arg1) {
  results.add(new String(arg1,i, length)); //hotspot here
}
```

---

As far as I can tell from my tests so far, memory-wise it's a wash (the char[] allocation is negligible and doesn't impact GC, both create the same number of new strings/the substring() memory-leak was fixed a while ago), and CPU wise the char[] version wins, on account of the constant lookup for substrings. Does that sound correct? Have I missed anything in my analysis?

---

**Notes on solution**
`functionB` seems to be a clear fastest, per the answer below. also note that there's a StringBuilder in functionParent - and StringBuilder has a 1append(char[], index, length)` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have memory pressure with `String` operations incorporating lots of `substring` and `append` like operations, you should become aware of the `CharSequence` abstraction. A lot of APIs are already prepared to work with these in place of a `String`.

Since `String` itself implements `CharSequence`, you can change your methods to accept `CharSequence` input instead of `String` without changing their usefulness. The `subSequence` implementation of `String` will do the same as `substring`, hence copy the contents, but you may create a subsequence without copying using [`CharBuffer.wrap(string, start, end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int)).

As said, most operations support `CharSequence` input, most notably for your use case

- [`StringBuilder.append(CharSequence s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))
- [`StringBuilder.append(CharSequence s, int start, int end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int))
- The already mentioned [`CharBuffer.wrap(CharSequence csq, int start, int end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int))

  There’s also [`CharSequence.subSequence(int start, int end)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#subSequence(int,%20int)), but as said, if the underlying sequence is a `String` you get a copy whereas `CharBuffer.wrap` guarantees non-copying behavior
- [`CharBuffer.wrap(char[] array, int offset, int length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(char[],%20int,%20int)) as the canonical way to get a `CharSequence` representation of a `char[]` array without copying
- [`String.contentEquals(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence))
- The entire regex package, if needed, see, e.g. [`Pattern.matcher(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher(java.lang.CharSequence))
- [etc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/?java/lang/class-use/CharSequence.html)

Note that `StringBuilder` also implements `CharSequence`, therefore allows a round-trip of your operations without ever needing to create an intermediate `String` copy.

Answer (score 2):

`String.substring` - in addition to bound checking, finishes by calling `new String(value, beginIndex, subLen)` - unless the result would have been the entire original String, in which case it just returns the original String.

So I would use your 2nd / "`functionB`" example.

Comment: that's a repeat of the `toCharArray` test above

Comment: @blueberryfields ?  - This one does not use `String.toCharArray()`, and does not use `String.substring`.

Comment: (i'm guessing you're looking at the source code of substring, and didn't notice that the reference you gave is using the internal character array, and not a string). you've convinced me that the toCharArray conversion is worth it though, since it saves on the bounds checks more than it costs in memcopy, and has 0 gc consequences

Comment: show me an implementation of new String(arg1,i, length)

Comment: I thought we were talking "Java-ish PseudoCode".  :-)  Updating answer to reflect.

Comment: your java-ish pseudocode is hiding a call to String.subString () ;)